# FFmpeg merge videos - High memory usage

Tags: memory, video, ffmpeg, android

I use FFmpeg in my Android app to merge videos together. I have compiled an executable file that is run using `ProcessBuilder`. I am finding that with  my recent FFmpeg build (updated FFmpeg and libraries to git master from a 2015 build: [some details](https://superuser.com/questions/1148520/ffmpeg-crf-compression-slower-on-master-than-old-version)) the FFmpeg process is now being killed by Android for high memory usage. Is there some way I can log where the memory is being used by FFmpeg? E.g. the frames are being loaded into memory much faster than X complex filter can process them?

```
ffmpeg -y -i new_504c08fa-6c0c-40e3-a59c-93a37d73d364.mp4 -i new_921ff756-bfd9-4ac0-b2fc-15c4d6a46c3d.mp4 -i video_stamp_720.png -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1280x720 -filter_complex [0:v]trim=0.0:14.59,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0_trim0];[0:a]atrim=0.0:14.59,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0_trim0];[v0_trim0]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(ow-iw*min(ow/iw\,oh/ih))/2:(oh-ih*min(ow/iw\,oh/ih))/2,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1.0:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=13.59:d=1.0:alpha=1,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p[v0];[a0_trim0]afade=t=in:st=0:d=1.0,afade=t=out:st=13.59:d=1.0[a_fade0];aevalsrc=0:d=0.0[na0];[na0][a_fade0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a0];[1:v]trim=0.0:4.65,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1_trim1];[1:a]atrim=0.0:4.65,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1_trim1];[v1_trim1]scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,720/ih),pad=1280:720:(ow-iw*min(ow/iw\,oh/ih))/2:(oh-ih*min(ow/iw\,oh/ih))/2,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1.0:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=3.65:d=1.0:alpha=1,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,setpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS+13.59/TB,fifo[v1];[a1_trim1]afade=t=in:st=0:d=1.0,afade=t=out:st=3.65:d=1.0[a_fade1];aevalsrc=0:d=13.59[na1];[na1][a_fade1]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a1];[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2[amixed];aevalsrc=0:d=0[sa0];[sa0][amixed]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[complete_audio];[complete_audio]volume=1.0[audio_vol];[3:v]trim=duration=18.24[over0];[over0][v0]overlay=eof_action=pass[over1];[over1][v1]overlay=eof_action=pass[over2];[over2][2:v]overlay=0:0,format=yuva420p[over3] -vcodec libx264 -preset faster -map [over3] -map [audio_vol] -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -strict -2 new_50a51bd8-9a96-4c6c-afb2-95a2e130de89.mp4 
ffmpeg version N-82612-g81147b5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9 (GCC) 20140827 (prerelease)
  configuration: --target-os=linux --prefix=/home/jon/workspace/writing-minds-ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --cc=/home/jon/Development/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/jon/Development/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/ --cross-prefix=/home/jon/Development/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --nm=/home/jon/Development/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm --sysroot=/home/jon/Development/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/ --disable-shared --enable-static --extra-cflags='-I/home/jon/workspace/writing-minds-ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a/include -O3 -fPIE -pie -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=armv7-a ' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/jon/workspace/writing-minds-ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a/lib -fPIE -pie' --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx264 --enable-jni --enable-mediacodec --enable-nonfree --enable-pic --enable-version3 --enable-zlib --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-outdevs --disable-decoders --enable-decoder='mpeg4,aac,h264,mpegvideo,mpeg1video,mpeg2video,png,mjpeg,rawvideo,mp3,pcm_s16le,pcm_u8' --disable-encoders --enable-encoder='mpeg4,aac,h264,libx264,mpeg1video,mpeg2video,png,mjpeg,libfdk_aac,rawvideo,pcm_s16le,wrapped_avframe' --disable-parsers --enable-parser='aac,mpeg4video,ac3,h261,h264,vc1,mpegvideo' --disable-demuxers --enable-demuxer='aac,h264,mpegvideo,m4v,mov,vc1,mp4,concat,image2,mpegts,mp3,pcm_s16le' --disable-muxers --enable-muxer='h264,mpeg1video,mpeg2video,m4v,mov,vc1,md5,mp4,image2,mpegts,segment,null' --disable-filters --enable-filter='aresample,scale,movie,overlay,color,fade,afade,pad,asetpts,amerge,aevalsrc,concat,amix,colorchannelmixer,eq,hue,atempo,hflip,vflip,transpose,volume,anullsrc'
  libavutil      55. 41.101 / 55. 41.101
  libavcodec     57. 66.107 / 57. 66.107
  libavformat    57. 58.100 / 57. 58.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 67.100 /  6. 67.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'new_504c08fa-6c0c-40e3-a59c-93a37d73d364.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.58.100
  Duration: 00:00:14.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1040 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 891 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 139 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'new_921ff756-bfd9-4ac0-b2fc-15c4d6a46c3d.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.58.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 932 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 778 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 140 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, image2, from 'video_stamp_720.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 478 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Video: png, pal8(pc), 1280x720, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #3, lavfi, from 'color=black:s=1280x720':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #3:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 0xb8b01f10] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0xb8b01f10] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0xb8b01f10] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0xb8b01f10] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=4 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=20 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'new_50a51bd8-9a96-4c6c-afb2-95a2e130de89.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.58.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.66.107 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.66.107 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> trim
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> atrim
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> trim
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> atrim
  Stream #2:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay
  Stream #3:0 (rawvideo) -> trim
  format -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  volume -> Stream #0:1 (libfdk_aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    4 fps=3.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.11 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.0988x    
frame=    7 fps=4.1 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.123x    
frame=   10 fps=4.5 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.34 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.158x    
frame=   13 fps=4.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.171x    
frame=   16 fps=5.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.58 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.18x    
frame=   19 fps=5.1 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.71 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.193x    
frame=   22 fps=5.1 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.81 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.19x    
frame=   25 fps=5.2 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.92 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.194x    
frame=   26 fps=4.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.97 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.151x    
frame=   29 fps=4.2 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.11 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.16x    
frame=   32 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:01.20 bitrate=  70.0kbits/s speed=0.161x    
frame=   34 fps=4.2 q=28.0 size=      23kB time=00:00:01.30 bitrate= 145.2kbits/s speed=0.162x    
frame=   35 fps=4.1 q=28.0 size=      34kB time=00:00:01.34 bitrate= 206.7kbits/s speed=0.158x    
frame=   37 fps=4.0 q=28.0 size=      59kB time=00:00:01.41 bitrate= 339.1kbits/s speed=0.152x    
frame=   40 fps=4.0 q=28.0 size=      96kB time=00:00:01.53 bitrate= 514.0kbits/s speed=0.155x    
frame=   43 fps=4.0 q=28.0 size=     128kB time=00:00:01.64 bitrate= 634.6kbits/s speed=0.152x    
frame=   47 fps=4.1 q=28.0 size=     170kB time=00:00:01.78 bitrate= 778.7kbits/s speed=0.158x    
frame=   50 fps=4.0 q=28.0 size=     210kB time=00:00:01.92 bitrate= 893.4kbits/s speed=0.155x    
frame=   53 fps=4.1 q=28.0 size=     267kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate=1072.2kbits/s speed=0.157x    
frame=   55 fps=4.1 q=28.0 size=     299kB time=00:00:02.13 bitrate=1146.5kbits/s speed=0.158x    
frame=   57 fps=4.1 q=28.0 size=     314kB time=00:00:02.20 bitrate=1167.5kbits/s speed=0.157x    
frame=   60 fps=4.1 q=28.0 size=     339kB time=00:00:02.34 bitrate=1184.0kbits/s speed=0.161x    
frame=   62 fps=4.1 q=28.0 size=     358kB time=00:00:02.41 bitrate=1214.4kbits/s speed=0.16x    
frame=   64 fps=4.1 q=28.0 size=     375kB time=00:00:02.48 bitrate=1235.9kbits/s speed=0.159x    
frame=   67 fps=4.1 q=28.0 size=     402kB time=00:00:02.60 bitrate=1264.9kbits/s speed=0.16x    
frame=   69 fps=4.1 q=28.0 size=     412kB time=00:00:02.71 bitrate=1241.1kbits/s speed=0.162x    
frame=   71 fps=4.1 q=28.0 size=     430kB time=00:00:02.78 bitrate=1263.6kbits/s speed=0.162x    
frame=   75 fps=4.2 q=28.0 size=     452kB time=00:00:02.92 bitrate=1266.4kbits/s speed=0.164x    
frame=   78 fps=4.2 q=28.0 size=     471kB time=00:00:03.04 bitrate=1269.5kbits/s speed=0.162x    
frame=   82 fps=4.2 q=28.0 size=     502kB time=00:00:03.20 bitrate=1283.3kbits/s speed=0.166x    
frame=   85 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=     519kB time=00:00:03.34 bitrate=1272.5kbits/s speed=0.168x    
frame=   88 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=     541kB time=00:00:03.45 bitrate=1280.4kbits/s speed=0.168x    
frame=   90 fps=4.2 q=28.0 size=     565kB time=00:00:03.52 bitrate=1312.2kbits/s speed=0.166x    
frame=   94 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=     593kB time=00:00:03.69 bitrate=1316.5kbits/s speed=0.169x    
frame=   96 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=     603kB time=00:00:03.78 bitrate=1304.4kbits/s speed=0.169x    
frame=   98 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=     624kB time=00:00:03.87 bitrate=1319.2kbits/s speed=0.17x    
frame=  101 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=     648kB time=00:00:03.97 bitrate=1337.3kbits/s speed=0.169x    
frame=  103 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=     661kB time=00:00:04.06 bitrate=1333.1kbits/s speed=0.17x    
frame=  107 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     695kB time=00:00:04.17 bitrate=1361.6kbits/s speed=0.171x    
frame=  108 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=     702kB time=00:00:04.24 bitrate=1353.3kbits/s speed=0.17x    
frame=  111 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=     719kB time=00:00:04.38 bitrate=1342.6kbits/s speed=0.172x    
frame=  114 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     742kB time=00:00:04.48 bitrate=1355.6kbits/s speed=0.172x    
frame=  116 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     762kB time=00:00:04.59 bitrate=1358.5kbits/s speed=0.173x    
frame=  118 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=     776kB time=00:00:04.64 bitrate=1369.2kbits/s speed=0.17x    
frame=  121 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     801kB time=00:00:04.78 bitrate=1372.5kbits/s speed=0.172x    
frame=  125 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     830kB time=00:00:04.89 bitrate=1387.8kbits/s speed=0.173x    
frame=  126 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     836kB time=00:00:04.96 bitrate=1378.1kbits/s speed=0.172x    
frame=  130 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     862kB time=00:00:05.13 bitrate=1376.7kbits/s speed=0.174x    
frame=  131 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     878kB time=00:00:05.17 bitrate=1389.4kbits/s speed=0.173x    
frame=  133 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     896kB time=00:00:05.24 bitrate=1399.4kbits/s speed=0.172x    
frame=  136 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     926kB time=00:00:05.38 bitrate=1408.7kbits/s speed=0.173x    
frame=  139 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     945kB time=00:00:05.50 bitrate=1406.9kbits/s speed=0.174x    
frame=  141 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     956kB time=00:00:05.57 bitrate=1404.6kbits/s speed=0.174x    
frame=  144 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     977kB time=00:00:05.71 bitrate=1401.1kbits/s speed=0.175x    
frame=  146 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=     989kB time=00:00:05.78 bitrate=1401.8kbits/s speed=0.174x    
frame=  149 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1014kB time=00:00:05.89 bitrate=1409.0kbits/s speed=0.175x    
frame=  151 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:05.96 bitrate=1406.1kbits/s speed=0.174x    
frame=  153 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1045kB time=00:00:06.06 bitrate=1413.2kbits/s speed=0.172x    
frame=  157 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1075kB time=00:00:06.22 bitrate=1414.6kbits/s speed=0.174x    
frame=  160 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1091kB time=00:00:06.33 bitrate=1409.4kbits/s speed=0.174x    
frame=  163 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1111kB time=00:00:06.45 bitrate=1410.1kbits/s speed=0.175x    
frame=  166 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1132kB time=00:00:06.57 bitrate=1411.7kbits/s speed=0.175x    
frame=  167 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1139kB time=00:00:06.61 bitrate=1410.4kbits/s speed=0.174x    
frame=  171 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1168kB time=00:00:06.78 bitrate=1411.0kbits/s speed=0.176x    
frame=  173 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1176kB time=00:00:06.84 bitrate=1406.7kbits/s speed=0.175x    
frame=  175 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1203kB time=00:00:06.94 bitrate=1419.3kbits/s speed=0.175x    
frame=  179 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1235kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate=1428.4kbits/s speed=0.176x    
frame=  180 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1250kB time=00:00:07.15 bitrate=1431.9kbits/s speed=0.175x    
frame=  183 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1277kB time=00:00:07.26 bitrate=1439.6kbits/s speed=0.176x    
frame=  186 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1300kB time=00:00:07.36 bitrate=1447.3kbits/s speed=0.175x    
frame=  189 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1323kB time=00:00:07.50 bitrate=1445.3kbits/s speed=0.176x    
frame=  192 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1349kB time=00:00:07.61 bitrate=1451.2kbits/s speed=0.177x    
frame=  195 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1369kB time=00:00:07.73 bitrate=1450.2kbits/s speed=0.176x    
frame=  198 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    1389kB time=00:00:07.84 bitrate=1449.5kbits/s speed=0.176x    
frame=  201 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1406kB time=00:00:07.96 bitrate=1446.2kbits/s speed=0.177x    
frame=  203 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1418kB time=00:00:08.05 bitrate=1442.2kbits/s speed=0.177x    
frame=  207 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1443kB time=00:00:08.21 bitrate=1438.4kbits/s speed=0.177x    
frame=  210 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1460kB time=00:00:08.35 bitrate=1430.8kbits/s speed=0.178x    
frame=  213 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1475kB time=00:00:08.45 bitrate=1429.3kbits/s speed=0.178x    
frame=  216 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1492kB time=00:00:08.56 bitrate=1426.5kbits/s speed=0.178x    
frame=  218 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1502kB time=00:00:08.66 bitrate=1420.5kbits/s speed=0.178x    
frame=  222 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1525kB time=00:00:08.80 bitrate=1419.9kbits/s speed=0.179x    
frame=  225 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1540kB time=00:00:08.93 bitrate=1411.3kbits/s speed=0.18x    
frame=  227 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1550kB time=00:00:09.03 bitrate=1405.7kbits/s speed=0.18x    
frame=  230 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1567kB time=00:00:09.12 bitrate=1406.6kbits/s speed=0.179x    
frame=  234 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1590kB time=00:00:09.28 bitrate=1402.0kbits/s speed=0.18x    
frame=  237 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1618kB time=00:00:09.40 bitrate=1409.5kbits/s speed=0.18x    
frame=  238 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1626kB time=00:00:09.45 bitrate=1409.1kbits/s speed=0.179x    
frame=  242 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1650kB time=00:00:09.61 bitrate=1405.9kbits/s speed=0.18x    
frame=  245 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    1665kB time=00:00:09.72 bitrate=1401.6kbits/s speed=0.18x    
frame=  249 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1685kB time=00:00:09.89 bitrate=1395.7kbits/s speed=0.181x    
frame=  252 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1700kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=1391.9kbits/s speed=0.181x    
frame=  255 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1710kB time=00:00:10.12 bitrate=1383.9kbits/s speed=0.181x    
frame=  258 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1725kB time=00:00:10.24 bitrate=1379.6kbits/s speed=0.181x    
frame=  261 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1738kB time=00:00:10.37 bitrate=1371.9kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  265 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1757kB time=00:00:10.54 bitrate=1365.0kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  268 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1781kB time=00:00:10.65 bitrate=1369.3kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  270 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1803kB time=00:00:10.72 bitrate=1377.1kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  273 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1825kB time=00:00:10.86 bitrate=1376.1kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  276 fps=4.6 q=25.0 size=    1853kB time=00:00:10.98 bitrate=1382.2kbits/s speed=0.181x    
frame=  280 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1878kB time=00:00:11.12 bitrate=1383.4kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  283 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1929kB time=00:00:11.26 bitrate=1403.6kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  285 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1945kB time=00:00:11.33 bitrate=1406.4kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  288 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1958kB time=00:00:11.44 bitrate=1401.2kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  290 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1975kB time=00:00:11.54 bitrate=1402.1kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  292 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    1985kB time=00:00:11.60 bitrate=1400.3kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  295 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2003kB time=00:00:11.74 bitrate=1396.7kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  298 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2028kB time=00:00:11.84 bitrate=1403.2kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  301 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2043kB time=00:00:11.98 bitrate=1397.0kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  304 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2059kB time=00:00:12.09 bitrate=1394.3kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  306 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2066kB time=00:00:12.16 bitrate=1390.9kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  309 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2085kB time=00:00:12.28 bitrate=1390.8kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  312 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2106kB time=00:00:12.42 bitrate=1388.7kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  314 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2130kB time=00:00:12.49 bitrate=1396.8kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  318 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2152kB time=00:00:12.65 bitrate=1393.0kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  320 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2168kB time=00:00:12.74 bitrate=1393.1kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  324 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2195kB time=00:00:12.88 bitrate=1395.0kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  328 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2215kB time=00:00:13.04 bitrate=1390.3kbits/s speed=0.184x    
frame=  330 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2232kB time=00:00:13.14 bitrate=1391.0kbits/s speed=0.184x    
frame=  334 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2257kB time=00:00:13.28 bitrate=1392.1kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  336 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2267kB time=00:00:13.39 bitrate=1386.2kbits/s speed=0.184x    
frame=  339 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2290kB time=00:00:13.49 bitrate=1390.5kbits/s speed=0.184x    
frame=  341 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:13.60 bitrate=1386.9kbits/s speed=0.184x    
frame=  343 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2314kB time=00:00:13.69 bitrate=1383.6kbits/s speed=0.184x    
frame=  345 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2328kB time=00:00:13.79 bitrate=1382.6kbits/s speed=0.184x    
frame=  347 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2335kB time=00:00:13.86 bitrate=1380.0kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  349 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2349kB time=00:00:13.93 bitrate=1381.2kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  351 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2357kB time=00:00:14.02 bitrate=1376.6kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  353 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2366kB time=00:00:14.11 bitrate=1373.1kbits/s speed=0.183x    
frame=  355 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2379kB time=00:00:14.16 bitrate=1376.0kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  357 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2395kB time=00:00:14.23 bitrate=1378.2kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  359 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2414kB time=00:00:14.32 bitrate=1380.1kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  361 fps=4.6 q=28.0 size=    2424kB time=00:00:14.39 bitrate=1379.1kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  363 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    2443kB time=00:00:14.48 bitrate=1381.1kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  365 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    2455kB time=00:00:14.60 bitrate=1377.2kbits/s speed=0.182x    
frame=  365 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    2455kB time=00:00:14.86 bitrate=1353.5kbits/s speed=0.184x    
frame=  365 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    2455kB time=00:00:15.11 bitrate=1330.7kbits/s speed=0.186x    
frame=  365 fps=4.5 q=28.0 size=    2455kB time=00:00:15.34 bitrate=1310.5kbits/s speed=0.187x    
frame=  365 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    2455kB time=00:00:15.51 bitrate=1296.8kbits/s speed=0.188x    
frame=  365 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    2455kB time=00:00:15.69 bitrate=1281.4kbits/s speed=0.189x    
frame=  365 fps=4.4 q=28.0 size=    2455kB time=00:00:15.97 bitrate=1259.1kbits/s speed=0.192x    
frame=  365 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=    2455kB time=00:00:16.16 bitrate=1244.6kbits/s speed=0.193x    
frame=  365 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=    2455kB time=00:00:16.39 bitrate=1227.0kbits/s speed=0.194x    
frame=  365 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=    2455kB time=00:00:16.62 bitrate=1209.9kbits/s speed=0.196x    
frame=  365 fps=4.3 q=28.0 size=    2455kB time=00:00:16.76 bitrate=1199.8kbits/s speed=0.196x    
processComplete: 9
```

I understand that my FFmpeg command does some unnecessary filtering, e.g. scale a 720p video to be 720p, but I didn't think this would be the main cause. It is in there because the command is automatically generated and is supposed to work with many input videos.

Comment: Drop the fifo filter and check. Ignore the errors broadcast by ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya. Without the fifo filter, the frames freeze in the second clip. It was suggested that I should use fifo to solve that. See http://superuser.com/questions/1141673/ffmpeg-trim-and-overlay-freeze-on-frame .

Comment: I know. But we're trying to identify the memory hog here.

Comment: Of course, sorry. Performing the same command as above (2 clips), except without fifo, completed without an error. Doubling everything up to 4 clips, ffmpeg is again killed due to high memory usage. So, some improvement.

Comment: I can see in dmesg on the device: <4>[ 9706.743390,3] send sigkill to 26935 (ffmpeg), adj 0, size 114805, fyi @Mulvya.